# MVC populating drop down list from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

Im pretty new to MVC. Im trying to populate a drop downlist with currencies retrieved from database. What am I doing wrong?

```
@model IEnumerable<DSABankSolution.Models.ExchangeRates>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Exchange Rates";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br /> <br /> 


     <input type="text" size="5" value="1" />
        @Html.DropDownList("currency", Model.Select(p => new SelectListItem{ Text = p.Name, Value = p.ID})) 
        to  
       @Html.DropDownList("currency", Model.Select(p => new SelectListItem { Text = p.Name, Value = p.ID }));
    <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" name="Convert" />
```

ExchangeRate Model:

```
public class ExchangeRates
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

ExchangeRate Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency> currency = CurrencyRepository.Instance.getAllCurrencies().ToList();
        //ViewBag.CurrencyID = new SelectList(currency, "ID");
        //ViewBag.Currency = new SelectList(currency, "Name");

        return View(currency);
    }
```

Currency Repository:

```
public List<CommonLayer.Currency> getAllCurrencies()
    {
        var query = from curr
                    in this.Entity.Currencies
                    select curr;

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Error I am getting:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CommonLayer.Currency]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DSABankSolution.Models.ExchangeRates]'.

Thanks!

Comment: Your passing an `IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency>` into a view expecting a model of  `IEnumerable<DSABankSolution.Models.ExchangeRates>`

Comment: You pass `CommonLayer.Currency` in controller, but you get `SABankSolution.Models.ExchangeRates` in View, Type mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all. You are returning a collection of `Currency` as shown by this code

`IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency> currency`

and yet your view expect as a collection of `ExchangeRates`

```
@model IEnumerable<DSABankSolution.Models.ExchangeRates>
```

so you either change the declaration in your view to

```
@model IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency>
```

or return a list of `ExchangeRates` from your controller method

Comment: so I need to pass the model, how can I do this?

Comment: How you can pass the right model is similar to how you pass the currency. So instead of querying for currencies then query for exchange rates. I think you know how to do that? So proably you have 
`this.Entity.ExchangeRates`? And then you can select from that.

Comment: tried changing view declaration to accept CommonLayer.Currency but then this error pops up:


Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to `System.Data.Entity` and `EntityFramework.dll`, you're using EF aren't you?

Comment: hadd to add this to my web.config: <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>

Answer (score 0):

Your view expects a strongly typed model of type

```
IEnumerable<DSABankSolution.Models.ExchangeRates>
```

However,you are passing

```
IEnumerable<CommonLayer.Currency>
```

back to view.